# Node position relative in one dimension but fixed in the other

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

[image]

I want to position the nodes "Herby I invite" and "to some event at my place" vertically *below of* resp. *above of* the name but horizontally I want to set the position to `10 mm`. How can I position a node relative to another in one dimension, but with a fixed value in the other dimension?

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm,y=1mm]
\clip (0,0) rectangle (154,111);
\node[draw] at (77,55.292) (name) {\LARGE Name of a Person};
\node[draw,align=left, above of=name, anchor=west] {Herby I invite};
\node[draw,align=left, below of=name, anchor=west] {to some event at my place};
\node[draw,align=left, anchor=west] at (10,30) (sender) {Yours Me};
\node[draw,align=left, anchor=west,yshift=-1cm] at (sender.south west) {My Place};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you illustrate with some hand drawings, what you like to have?  With  `below right=<horizontal distance> and  <vertical distance> of <coordinate>` you can places node where you like to have in respect to `<coordinate>`.

Comment: One solution is to specify two points A and B and use (A -| B) or (A |- B).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to calculate an extra `xshift`.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\newlength\coor@x
\newlength\coor@y
\def\extract@xy#1{
  \path (#1);
  \pgfgetlastxy{\coor@x}{\coor@y}
}
\tikzset{
  test/.code args={#1 at #2}{
    \extract@xy{#1}
    \pgfkeysalso{xshift={#2-\coor@x}}
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm,y=1mm]
\clip (0,0) rectangle (154,111);
\node[draw] at (77,55.292) (name) {\LARGE Name of a Person};
\node[draw,align=left, above of=name, anchor=west, test=name at 10mm] {Herby I invite};
\node[draw,align=left, below of=name, anchor=west, test=name at 10mm] {to some event at my place};
\node[draw,align=left, anchor=west] at (10,30) (sender) {Yours Me};
\node[draw,align=left, anchor=west,yshift=-1cm] at (sender.south west) {My Place};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]